# Can't make an ext4-partition on a specific raid

Tags: system-installation, ext4, ssd, ntfs, raid1

I have a hardware raid-1 on two WDC-SSDs with 500GB on each SSD. The raid controller is a Marvell-88SE9128 via two GSATA connections (the controller is directly on the motherboard and not an ePCI extension card).

When I try to install a Linux distribution on this raid, every installer I tried so far fails, with a more or less unspecific error message. (Until now I tried Arch, Ubuntu, Ubuntu-Server, Debian, CentOS and Rocky)

With GParted-Live I could see, that the creation of an ext4 partition fails. GParted reports a success, but directly after closing the success message the partion is gone and GParted don't detect it anymore on the raid-volume.

The interesting thing is, a ntfs partition stays and can be accessed! (I did not find any hard ties between Marvell and Microsoft.)

I also tried `mkfs` with a live system, but same result: success message, but no partition.

I already read the documentation for the marvell chip in the manuall from my motherboard and the following datasheets from Marvell:

- https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/storage/marvell-storage-88se912x-product-brief-2010-08.pdf
- https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/storage/marvell-storage-88se9130-datasheet-2018-08.pdf
- None of them (and nobody/nothing else I found on the Internet) says, that it is only for ntfys.

Is something similar happened to anyone else or does someone know how to apply an ext4-partiton on a raid like this?

Many thanks in advance

Edit:
As suggested, I used a Ubuntu livesystem and looked up the dmesg. This is the result:

```
[  780.345795] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 16061 MB/s
[  780.413795] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  8934 MB/s
[  780.481797] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 17492 MB/s
[  780.549807] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  9685 MB/s
[  780.617795] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 13970 MB/s
[  780.685797] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  8287 MB/s
[  780.685801] raid6: using algorithm sse2x2 gen() 17492 MB/s
[  780.685802] raid6: .... xor() 9685 MB/s, rmw enabled
[  780.685804] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[  780.687460] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
[  780.722675] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel, zoned=yes
[  780.751206] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[  780.804405] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, quota, no debug enabled
[  938.260634]  sdj:
[  938.723894]  sdj:
[  938.799655]  sdj:
[  952.400893]  sdj:
[  952.524131]  sdj: sdj1
[  953.237100]  sdj: sdj1
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation NF200 PCIe 2.0 switch (rev a3)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation NF200 PCIe 2.0 switch (rev a3)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation NF200 PCIe 2.0 switch (rev a3)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100 [GeForce GTX 470] (rev a3)
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF100 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT8892E PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 10)
08:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
09:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
0a:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
0c:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9128 PCIe SATA 6 Gb/s RAID controller with HyperDuo (rev 11)
0d:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9128 PCIe SATA 6 Gb/s RAID controller with HyperDuo (rev 11)
```

blkid:

```
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="INTENSO" UUID="8C09-B4FF" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="c3072e18-01"
/dev/sdi1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2021-07-19-22-56-21-00" LABEL="GParted-live" TYPE="iso9660" PARTUUID="11ddad15-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/md126: UUID="f32d4848-9784-4912-b0ab-ff250bf69dfc" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
/dev/md127: UUID="ec6af278-b3f8-4fc2-94c9-97029c302e14" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
/dev/sda: UUID="14e609d1-2017-96b5-4cf8-af002dd538ed" UUID_SUB="3646b87c-950c-e4b3-a855-f93f3e5a88d2" LABEL="ubuntu-server:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="14e609d1-2017-96b5-4cf8-af002dd538ed" UUID_SUB="5a703c43-f3eb-203e-5bb4-3fa2a2acf223" LABEL="ubuntu-server:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdh: UUID="bcd188a7-5c15-8245-8c7a-761d509bad19" UUID_SUB="a72121fc-ebe3-88e2-cba9-9b74f198bed1" LABEL="ubuntu-server:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdj: UUID="bcd188a7-5c15-8245-8c7a-761d509bad19" UUID_SUB="419122c5-a305-a607-a0d9-9a5b2f1aed89" LABEL="ubuntu-server:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
```

lsblk:

```bsh
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 341,2M  1 loop  /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
sda       8:0    0  10,9T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0  10,9T  0 raid1 
sdb       8:16   0  10,9T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0  10,9T  0 raid1 
sdc       8:32   1 967,5M  0 disk  
└─sdc1    8:33   1   966M  0 part  /media/intenso
sdh       8:112  0  14,6T  0 disk  
└─md126   9:126  0  14,6T  0 raid1 
sdi       8:128  1   7,5G  0 disk  
└─sdi1    8:129  1   396M  0 part  /usr/lib/live/mount/medium
sdj       8:144  0  14,6T  0 disk  
└─md126   9:126  0  14,6T  0 raid1 
sdk       8:160  0 465,7G  0 disk
```

Some explanations:

- `sda` and `sdb` are combined to a Software Raid1 `md127`.
- `sdh` and `sdj` are combined to a Software Raid1 `md126`.
- Raids `md126` and `md127` are combined to a LUKS encrypted LVM.
- `sdc` and `sdi` are some USB sticks need for the live system.
- `sdk` is the hardware Raid1 whick won't hold a ext4-partition.

Comment: It's not about ext4, it's about the Linux kernel being unable to use your storage. There must be errors in `dmesg`.

Comment: The `dmesg` excerpt you showed is absolutely useless. I think. I don't see anything related to this problem. Please boot the system with disks installed into some live Linux distribution (*any* will do, provided there are all needed tools installed), and show us the output of the following commands: `lspci`, `lsblk`, `blkid`.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your patience. It took some time, because we tried to solve it with a software raid, but this don't work out either. At least not as we want it to. So here we are again. I'm still thankfull for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [ljrk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100496/ljrk) we were able to figure out, that `Parted` and `GParted` can not partioning the RAID-Disk. We still do not know what the exact Problem for `Parted/GParted` is, because no error message appears, like I told before.

This made it very difficult to install Ubuntu or any other Debian derivate, but `fdisk` and `gdisk` are still working as expected.

So we partitioned the RAID-Disk manually and installed Arch. (We tried Arch before, but with `Parted`, so it did not work out either). It is not exactly what we wanted, but also good, so I am closing this question.